# Is socket sys (libc) function supposed to always return the same result for the same parameters?

Tags: socket, ioctl

I am writing a C# app that basically does a similar job that [iwlist](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools).
I am having trouble, though, in porting the [IOCTL](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) calls into .NET. I mean, the interop code I have written so far (to enable my .NET app call this unmanaged sys code) does not successfully perform ioctl calls, always returning -1 as error.
I notice that while I debug iwlist in Visual Studio Code in linux, I always see that the call [socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html)(2,2,0) returns file descriptor 3.

Running the same call with the exact same parameters from my C# app - returns a file descriptor in the range 200 and above.

Since iwlist further ioctl calls take the returned socket as an input parameter, I wonder if this in itself is an indication of my problem. In other words, am I supposed to expect my ported c# iwlist code to run when iwlist original code always get a file descriptor 3 as the socket opened, and the C# app never does ?

From the docs:

> The file descriptor
> returned by a successful call will be the lowest-numbered file
> descriptor not currently open for the process.

If so, why on debug I always get the same file descriptor ?

Comment: If you are rerunning the same application in each debug run then you probably have the same file descriptors open and so the lowest numbered one which is not currently open will remain the same.

Comment: @icarus: that is what I do, I can understand this throughout multiple runs in a given time frame. But throughout different days (after different boots)... I never got anything else than 3 while debugging.

Comment: I doubt this is an indication of a problem.  It just sounds like c# holds open a larger number of fds.  While debugging find the PID (process ID eg `1234`) and look at the the directory `/proc/1234/fd`. This will show the fds currently held open by the process.

Comment: If this is the first file or socket you opened then getting 3 is expected, 0,1 and 2 are stdin, stdout and stderr so 3 is the lowest not used. If you really really want a different number then open a file before you do the socket call. Then FD 3 will be the file and your socket will return 4.

Answer (score 1):

Most POSIX library functions that return new file descriptors allocate the lowest-numbered descriptor number that is not in use. One notable exception to this is the `dup2` function whose purpose it is to duplicate a descriptor to a specific number: `dup2(old, new)` returns `new`.

If you write a loop in which you call `socket` with certain arguments such that a descriptor is returned, and you `close` that descriptor, and no other threads are allocating or destroying descriptors, then `socket` should return the same descriptor number each time.

That number refers to a different object each time; it's similar to re-using a memory allocation that has been freed.